# Mini batch size and reset states

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

3 is a big file, but I would like to reset the state after `mini_batch_size` of 50.

```
n_epoch=10000
n_batch=50

# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(3,batch_input_shape =(n_batch,trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2]),stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("linear"))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
model.summary()

#fitting model
for i in range(n_epoch):
    history=model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=n_batch,verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
```

I am getting the error:

```
value error:  In a stateful network, you should only pass inputs with a number of samples that can be divided by the batch size. Found: 63648 samples<
```

How can I train a LSTM in `mini_batch` size of 50 (a number which is not divisible by trainX)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make your training data a shape that **is** divisible by 50.
    In [1]: sample_size = 63648

```
In [2]: to_remove = sample_size % 50

In [3]: end_index = sample_size - to_remove

In [4]: model.fit(trainX[:end_index], trainY[:end_index], ...
```

---

What are the dimensions of `trainX` and `trainY`? You are not specifying a validation dataset, is that intentional?

You say you want to reset the state after a mini-batch, but you are resetting the state after each epoch (one loop through your entire dataset).

One more comment: the `n_epochs = 10000` seems excessive.

Comment: trainX=(63648,3,1), trainY=(6245,1) .I removed validation_split. Actually it was giving error when i set n_batch=len(trainX).  I did the above changes..set n_epoch=1300 as i want to cover the full train data with batch size of 50. model is runing. how can i set state after each mini_batch?

Comment: like as you said if i am doing using for loop and setting epoch=1, will it see entire dataset in each epoch or it will see only mini batch in each epoch?

Comment: It will reset the state after each single epoch. I only mention is because you had started by saying you want to reset after each mini-batch. But that would basically be the same as just setting `stateful=False`.

Comment: ok .so that means if i use mini_batch size and set stateful = false.it will automatically reset the states after each mini batch.  next error i am getting ,,...if i set validation split =0.1%. model is not runing. Error: cannot feed input of(40,3,1) into an lstm of(50,3,1). what should i do now? How to edit if want validation split as well?

Comment: hello.. by using the method you proposed my dataset is chopped.. now i have 63000 in train X. so i lost 648..  i dont want it like this. it is a time series data and i want all the data in series. if i will chop then i will lose the information. so i think this is not correct method for my problem. Thank you for the solution. can you please suggest something else?

Comment: You can just remove the statefulness of the LSTM layer, then you are more flexible with creating batch sizes. Otherwise you might consider looking into more traditional time-series analysis methods, such as ARMA or ARIMA, GARCH (for volatility) or even something like GLM models, If you google those letters with time-series, I'm sure you will find good resources.

Comment: ok.. thanks a lot. I will check these models for  details.